# In PHP, can you split a function up so it auto-detects a variable function adjusts the logic accordingly

Tags: php

I'm imagining something like:

Say you have `Model->Find('column_name', 'value')` and you want to call database records with the field name as part of the function call, e.g. `Model->FindByEmail('value')`

Could you make it so your class was smart enough to know that all `Model->FindByX()` calls are really just a dynamic wrapper for `Model->Find('column_name', 'value')`?

Comment: Sure, you could do that.

Comment: It is done with `__call` magic function.

Comment: Can you give me a rough idea on how? Been looking through the PHP documentation on variable functions and nothing stands out.

Comment: :O! 

Thanks @u_mulder

Comment: Note that IMO such syntactical sugar can be detrimental in the long run. An explicitly implemented API is less confusing and simpler (albeit possibly more verbose) than a magical implicit one. But again, that's just my 0.02€.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's Magic Method __call()

```
class MyClass {
  public function find($key, $value) {
    ...
  }
  public function __call($name, $args) {
    if (strpos($name, 'findBy') === 0 && count($args) === 1) {
      $key = substr($name, 6); //skip 6 characters of "findBy"
      //if you want the key lower case:
      // $key = strtolower($key);
      return $this->find($key, $args[0]);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

But this is slower in performance than a normal call, it can also generate confusion and most PHP IDEs will mark it as warning because it is difficult to debug.